# How to create candidate key in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli, cakephp-3.0

[I want to create candidate key (as primary key ) using program_id, location_id, course_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tpGU.png)

Comment: yes but through cakephp 3, i want to create key combine of three key(program_id,location_id, course_id)

Comment: Your question is very vague. "_Create candiate key in cakephp 3_" could be interpreted as issuing SQL commands via the CakePHP model layer to create primary key constraints in a database. It could also be interpreted as configuring the model layer to recognize a primary key constraint that already exists in a database. In any case it's also unclear what specific problem you have in doing any of this. Please update your question so that the actual intent, and the specific programming related problem with the task becomes clear.

Comment: See **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated per comment** - originally thought this was a 2.0 question.

CakePHP 3 does support for [composite keys](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html#indexes-and-constraints):

```
class YourTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('table_name');
        $this->primaryKey(['program_id', 'location_id', 'course_id']);
    }
}
```

As well as composite relationships:

```
$this->belongsTo('Students', [
    'foreignKey' => ['program_id', 'location_id', 'course_id'],
]);
```

---

**Previous Answer:**

CakePHP 2.0 was designed to work with singular primary keys, per their [docs on Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions):

> CakePHP does not support composite primary keys. If you want to directly manipulate your join table data, use direct query calls or add a primary key to act on it as a normal model.

You could instead specify the combo as a UNIQUE field in MySQL, but CakePHP will expect a single field for it's key, by default "id".

Comment: The question is tagged as CakePHP 3, and CakePHP 3 does support composite keys almost everywhere (the tree and translate behaviors are examples of where they aren't supported yet).